# css :not problem when body or * is specified in style

Tags: css

I'm learning css and trying to change background-color of all html except one div tag using `:not` element.

When i put like `body:not(.one)` it is changing background-color of whole html but not excluding the div mentioned in :not condition. Same problem if i use `*:not(.one)` Am i doing correct?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

body:not(.one)
{

background-color:blue;
}
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="one">
this is first div
</div>
<div >
this is second div
</div>
<p>
this  is a paragraph
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what browsers have you tested?

Comment: i have tested in chrome 13 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background color of your div is transparent. It looks to me like you're setting the body color and then expecting the div to be white or such like.

Given the CSS rule you're using, it's only styling the body tag anyway. You don't need to tell it not to style the div because it wasn't going to anyway.

The `not()` selector comes in handy when you want to style all `div`s for example, except ones that have a given class, such as:

```
div:not(.items){ /* some styles */}
```

This makes sens because there may be many `div` that we want to style, except `div` with the class `items`.

Your example in the question doesn't make so much sense because you're styling the `body` of which there's only one.

Your statement actually says:

Style all body tags except any body tag that has the class name `one`.

Comment: yes you are correct. when i put div it's working. So, is it like we should not use :not selector like *:not() and body:not() but should specify some element?

Comment: *:not() makes more sense than body:not() because in the first example you're selecting all elements, except for some with a class. In the second example you're selecting only 1 tag anyway. I've not much experience using :not() for real. I've never had a need for it.

Answer (score 0):

The `:not` selector is a CCS3 feature which not many browser support. Which browser are you testing in?

If all browsers are to be supported you should probably look into a javascript/jquery solution.

Comment: i have tested in chrome 13 and mozilla 6 version